# Async methods mvc c# msdn example

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm trying to follow the example of this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=vs.98).aspx) about async calls in MVC

I'm trying to make the same code to see how it works, but I have a problem with this part:

```
SportsService sportsService = new SportsService();
sportsService.GetScoresCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    AsyncManager.Parameters["scores"] = e.Value;
    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
};
sportsService.GetScoresAsync();
```

The methods **GetScoresCompleted** and **GetScoresAsync** are not implemented in the example, and I don't know how to implement them.

Can someone give me an example or a link to an example of how this methods have to be implemented?

Comment: See [Implementing the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873177(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I tried reading this but I did not get it completly...

Comment: In the end this link lead me to this link [link](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/working-with-asynchronous-operations-in-asp.net-mvc.htm) that help me to acomplish what I was looking for, if te coment where an answere I will mark it as valid.

Comment: You should perhaps post an answer to your own question with a demonstration of how you implemented `GetScoresAsync`, SO doesn't recommend link-only answers.